# Case insensitive search in Apache solr

Tags: php, search, solr

I created a search application with the type string in Solr with PHP and is working fine. The only issue found is it can not support case insensitive search. Upon searching i found that solr doesn't support case insensitive search with the type "String".

So i created a custom type "string_ci" and configured as below.

```
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> -
    <field name="loc_code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="loc_name" type="string_ci" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="state" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

This is my field type definition for "string_ci"

```
    <fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField"
            sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>           
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
       </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. Can someone point out where i went wrong ?

Comment: check links:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071164/solr-case-insensitive-search-do-not-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true"    omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```